# How to find the number of repetitions of an item in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I find the times that 1 (for example) is repeated in this array?

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 6];
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are not supposed to ask basic “how can I” questions here, but to do some initial research, and ideally based on that also try something, yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
 function getOccurrence(myArray, value) {
        var count = 0;
        myArray .forEach((val) => (val === value && count++));
        return count;
    }
```